# INSERT INTO with SELECT (only subset of columns and column ordering)

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

**Problem:** I want to insert rows that are present in `dummy_data_temp` (but not present) into `dummy_data`. `dummy_data` consists of 10 columns and `dummy_data_temp` only of a subset of these columns (4 and these 4 columns have column index 2, 6, 9, 10 in `dummy_data`). For this I use the query below

When running this command I get the following error:

> Warning: Error in postgresqlExecStatement: RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  column "XXX" is of type double precision but expression is of type text
>
> ```
> LINE 1: INSERT INTO dummy_data SELECT dummy_data_temp.* FROM dummy_d...
>                                       ^
> HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.`
> ```

**Question:** Is there a way to insert the selected columns by name reference or must the `dummy_data_temp` always consist of the same columns (and column ordering) as `dummy_data`?

```
INSERT INTO dummy_data 
SELECT dummy_data_temp.* 
FROM dummy_data_temp 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dummy_data ON (dummy_data.id=dummy_data_temp.id) 
WHERE (dummy_data.id IS NULL)
```

Comment: Yes, you need to list out all columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify target and source columns:

```
INSERT INTO dummy_data (column_2, column_6, column_9, column_10)
SELECT t.col4, t.col2, t.col1, c.col3
FROM dummy_data_temp t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dummy_data dd ON dd.id = t.id
WHERE dd.id IS NULL;
```

(A NOT EXISTS condition might be more efficient though)